# How do I add LWJGL 3.1.1 to netbeans to use in a Java project?

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

I want to use the Light Weight Java Gaming Library(LWJGL) to my Netbeans so I can use it in my Java application.  The only videos that I can find show the zip file that they downloaded with separate src and doc folders inside of it.  The zip file that I download has everything in one directory.  I went to lwjgl.org/download and clicked on Stable and then Generate Bundle.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you generate a zip bundle? Because there is an option to set up maven or gradle project.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 were you successful?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I know this is an older question, but nonetheless would it be nice, if you could accept the answer if it had helped you out back then. I have tons of posts like this and it kinda sucks for the effort that was being made. Would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently.

[image: LWJGL-Netbeans-Setup-Step-1] So, to begin you want to go to **Tools** in the context menu and select **Libraries** (as shown). Next you can add a new library and name it e.g. **LWJGL-3.1.1** confirm with ok. You can find 3 tabs in the current window **Classpath**, **Sources** and **Javadoc**. There you add your jar files accordingly (in the downloaded .zip file you find .jar files with different names like **lwjgl-{whatever}-sources.jar** or **lwjgl-{whatever}-javadocs.jar**) make sure you put them in the right place. You have to repeat this process for all of the jar files you want. The javadoc files are not required but recommended. Make sure you also collect all the native .dll files and merge them in a folder called `\natives`. You find them in these jar files that are called like: **lwjgl-{whatever}-{your-OS}.jar**.

[image: LWJGL-Netbeans-Setup-Step-2]

Once you have finished the setup for your library right click on your current project and choose **Add Library...**. In the window that pops up you scroll down until you find your library that you have just created and you are almost done now.

[image: LWJGL-Netbeans-Setup-Step-3]

Last but not least go to the project settings. Select **Run** and make sure that you set the classpath in **VM options** to something like in the image: `-Djava.library.path="C:\java_workspace\LWJGL Library 3.1\natives`. Now this classpath tells netbeans where your native files are located. Your `\natives` folder that you should have created in the beginning is where this path should lead to. That's it. This is all you have to do for a setup without the use of maven, gradle, ...

[image: LWJGL-Netbeans-Setup-Finished]

You can test if it is working with the code provided by [LWJGL HelloWorld example](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide).

I hope this solved your problem.
Best regards.